# Knex.js migration issue: Fails with ` relation "knex_migrations" does not exist`

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I've been using knex.js successfully for a while now on this project, first time I've come accross this. I deleted all my migration files and dropped my db (locally) and instead used pg_dump to get the DDL and all data from my prod database (not including knex_migrations or knex_migrations_lock tables).

I created a new migration script and used `knex.raw` to paste all the SQL in. When I ran the migration script, I get the following:

`error: insert into "knex_migrations" ("batch", "migration_time", "name") values ($1, $2, $3) - relation "knex_migrations" does not exist`

This migration script is being run on a brand new database. When I change what's in the script to just be basic DDL, it works fine. So something about the result of pg_dump and trying to run it using knex is causing it to bomb out.

This isn't a ton of data either really, so I'm not too sure where I'm going wrong - knex is responsible for creating the migration tables and I've made sure there's no mention of knex or migration tables in the DDL.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

I just went down this hole. The following line is the culprit.

```
SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);
```

It's removing your search path so knex doesn't know where to find anything.

Answer (score -1):

The table `knex_migrations` and `knex_migrations_lock` will be created on running the command

`knex migrate:make <name of migration>`

Could you please confirm you have executed above knex command.

Once that is done running

`knex migrate:latest`

should create all schema you have mention.  knex.raw

Answer (score -1):

Using pd_dump to dump a database to an sql file, there occurs some additional lines in the beginning of the sql such as:

```sql
SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET xmloption = content;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET row_security = off;
```

comment those out and the migration should work. You can uncomment one statement at a time to see which one is causing the problem.